# Form Validation in Javascript. I want to validate a field so that it only accepts car registrations in the form of "KK-10-HUH"

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to create a javascript function which will validate a short form and only accept a Car Registration number in the format of "KM-10-HUH". "KM" being 2 letters, "10" being 2 numbers and "HUH" being 3 letters. All 3 parts should be separated via a hyphen (-).

Here is a sample of some of my code:

```
    <div>
        <form id="registrationForm" method="post"  onSubmit="return validate();">
            <table cols="2" width="100%">                   
                <tr>
                    <td>Model<span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="30" id = "model" name = "model" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Registration Number <span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="30" id = "regNumber" name="regNumber" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name<span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="30" id = "name" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>                   

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There's no "code" only markup of your form. And it is a typical "write complete solution for me" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for that.

```
var regex = /[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}/g;
```

Then to test if plate string is valid:

```
regex.test("KM-10-HUH"); // returns true
regex.test("KM-1-HUH"); // returns false
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION BELOW**

`[A-Z]` means ANY character from A to Z, (uppercase letters only),
`{2}` at the end, means that there has to be 2 of whatever was written before it, in this case

`[A-Z]{2}` means 2 upper case letters. Then just a hyphen, then 3 numbers `[0-9]{3}`, a hyphen and three letters again `[A-Z]{3}`.

Comment: I've created a fiddle to show you. For some reasons writing the JS code in the JS section didn't work. So all the code is written in the HTML section.

https://jsfiddle.net/dLs5nc7t/

Answer (score 2):

Combining the two other answers, try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLs5nc7t/1/

I.e. just put the regex into a `pattern` attribute on the `input` tag:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="regNumber" name="regNumber"
       pattern="[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}" />
```

This negates the need for JavaScript, since the browser will not allow the form to be submitted while that field contains text not matching the pattern.

Comment: I've actually used that. It's really handy, plus you can set the custom message which will be displayed if the pattern isn't matched. But it was not widely supported tho. Is it now?

Comment: Oh and it has to have the "required" attribute, doesn't seem to work without it :D

Comment: @LukaKvavilashvili re support c.f. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern .  Also I'm not sure about the 'required' part--it seemed to work for me in the fiddle (it stopped submission with the wrong pattern with a popup) on Chrome...

Comment: @LukaKvavilashvili yeah that is strange.  C.f. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp where no example has `required`.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on OS X, and without the ``required`` attribute the form gets submitted for some weird reason..

Comment: @LukaKvavilashvili good to know...that's quite interesting.  I didn't detail before but my experience was on Chrome "Version 55.0.2883.87 Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 18.1 (64-bit)."

Answer (score 1):

You can learn a lot about form validation at this [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation). You can also use HTML5 form validation, specifying a pattern for the particular input that you are looking at using regular expressions.